# What is the meaning of perfect hatred?

Tags: psalms

Psalm 139:21-22
Berean Study Bible

> 21 Do I not hate those who hate You, O LORD,
> and detest those who rise against You?
> 22I hate them with **perfect hatred**;
> I count them as my enemies.

Comment: absolute hatred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is the meaning of perfect hatred?**

Most of our English translations follow the KJV which has "perfect hatred", the NASB has "utmost hatred " and the NABRE has  "fierce hatred". I am personally at a loss and do not understand what exactly "perfect hatred" means

Psalm 139:21-22  (NASB)

> 21 Do I not hate those who hate You, Lord? And do I not loathe those
> who rise up against You? 22 I hate them with the **utmost hatred;**  They
> have become my enemies.

Psalm 139:21-22 (NABRE)

> 21 Do I not hate, Lord, those who hate you?   Those who rise against
> you, do I not loathe?  22 With **fierce hatred** I hate them,  enemies I
> count as my own.

Why did  the Psalmist  David loathe those wicked people?,in verse 20 he explains;" For they speak against You wickedly,  And Your enemies take Your name in vain. (NASB)

Because the wicked were guilty of bloodshed and of bringing reproach on God’s name, David declared; (Read verses 21-22 above)   David felt a loathing for these men because they intensely hated  God and were revolting against Him. They were the psalmist’s foes because he abhorred their wickedness, godlessness, and rebellion against the Most High.

Comment: Many thanks for this good answer.

Answer (score 2):

"Perfect hatred" translates תַּכְלִ֣ית שִׂנְאָ֣ה. This can also be translated "complete hatred"

[Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565632060) (p. 479). Oxford: Clarendon Press.

> †תַּכְלִית S8503 TWOT982f GK9417 n.f. *end, completeness*;...

In Semitic thought, hatred can be a mere contrast to love; even a lesser love, such as:

**Luke 14:26** ([ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2014%3A26&version=ESV))

> “If anyone comes to me and does not hate his own father and mother and wife and children and brothers and sisters, yes, and even his own life, he cannot be my disciple.

[Eli Lizorkin-Eyzenberg, *Becoming Israel*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YKSJB47). p. 68, pdf p. 72.

> In fact, the idea of “disliking, hating or favoring someone less” works quite differently in Biblical Hebrew.
> This is especially true when it is expressed in contrast of “loving someone.” The phraseology expresses the idea of intensity of feeling in comparison. In other words, “Jacob I loved… Esau I hated” (Mal. 1:2-3) is rendered quite literally in our modern terms. Translated from ancient Hebrew and interpreted into our modern way of speaking it could arguably mean something like “Esau I loved, but Jacob I favored with my great covenantal love.” The same is the case with Jesus’ statement that one must love Him and hate his parents (Luke 14:26). This is an idiomatic Hebraism that makes a comparison and does not actually instruct one to express hatred towards one’s parents. That would be absurd, given God’s explicit commandment to honor them.

Thus, this means real hatred like we think of it in English.

Comment: Very insightful tin include Luke! That really does explain it.

Answer (score 0):

The context of this verse is a Psalm that has one main theme - how well God knows us. The psalmist then speaks of the wicked whom God, as the only One who possesses such perfect knowledge of all, will slay.

God's perfect knowledge of every human being is contrasted with the the Psalmist's perfect hatred of those wicked people.

How could David, himself a sinner saved by grace, say that he has perfect hatred for others still in need of that same grace? Because of the thought that over archs the entire Psalm - the fact that God has this intimate knowledge of him, tells him that God hates not the sinner but only sin.

He then ends the psalm by asking the Being with such intimate knowledge of him, to probe what is unknown to him at the moment. He is not conscious of any sin he practices against God but he knows how deceptive his heart is. God alone can help him here.

He therefore hates them with the same perfect hatred that God does. The following statement helps me see it applied in a different context:

> God is not pleased with the slothful work done in the churches. He expects His stewards to be true and faithful in giving reproof and correction. They are to expel wrong after the rule God has given in His Word, not according to their own ideas and impulses. No harsh means must be used, no unfair, hasty, impulsive work done. The efforts made to cleanse the church from moral uncleanness must be made in God's way. There must be no partiality, no hypocrisy. There must be no favorites, whose sins are regarded as less sinful than those of others. Oh, how much we all need the baptism of the Holy Ghost. Then we shall always work with the mind of Christ, with kindness, compassion, and sympathy, showing love for the sinner while hating sin with a perfect hatred." 1888 Materials p.144. Ellen G. White.

Hating sin and not the sinner is as tall an order as perfection of any kind would seem to imperfect beings. Through a proper relation to and appreciation of Christ and what He has done for us, we gain the same perfect hatred of sinners.